# footer div elements overlapping

Tags: css

Im having a problem with my footer ( started learning css two days ago).this is the bottom of my page:
https://gyazo.com/b681e5ca06f7f89bac727ea20a1ff3dd

now i want the links to stick to the bottom without  manipulating margins seperately for each div. So i tried to make the parent div have position:relative and the insider element have position:absolute.
what happens is this:
https://gyazo.com/0031cbb528e4c80600f1533f4b60993d

the relevant code for CSS:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}
.infotype {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    bottom: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

relevant code for HTML:

```
<section class="row">
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="infotype data">
                    <h3>Rockets and spacecraft</h3>
                    <a href="#">Falcon 9</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Falcon Heavy</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Dragon</a>
                </div>
                <div class="infotype updates">
                    <h3>Updates</h3>
                    <a class="info" href="#">News</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Launch Manifest</a>
                </div>
                <div class="infotype about">
                    <h3>About SpaceX</h3>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Company</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Careers</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Gallery</a><br>
                    <a class="info" href="#">Shop</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

sorry for my poor formatting skills, like i mentioned im new here.

Comment: what if you remove position: absolute?

Comment: thats the thing- when i remove it i get the first picture i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the floats and absolute positioning, using flexboxes for the layout instead. You can read about flexboxes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
 I also removed the line breaks in the HTML.

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.infotype {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section class="row">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="infotype data">
      <h3>Rockets and spacecraft</h3>
      <a href="#">Falcon 9</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Falcon Heavy</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Dragon</a>
    </div>
    <div class="infotype updates">
      <h3>Updates</h3>
      <a class="info" href="#">News</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Launch Manifest</a>
    </div>
    <div class="infotype about">
      <h3>About SpaceX</h3>
      <a class="info" href="#">Company</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Careers</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Gallery</a>
      <a class="info" href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the footer links still dont stick to the bottom of the page

Comment: oh i found the pproblem- in the code you sent it should be "flex-end" instead of start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `html` and `css`. Just create an inner div for `.infotype` to make `position: absolute` work correctly.

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}
.infotype {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.infotype-inner{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

<section class="row">
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="infotype data">
                    <div class="infotype-inner">
                        <h3>Rockets and spacecraft</h3>
                        <a href="#">Falcon 9</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Falcon Heavy</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Dragon</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="infotype updates">
                    <div class="infotype-inner">
                        <h3>Updates</h3>
                        <a class="info" href="#">News</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Launch Manifest</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="infotype about">
                    <div class="infotype-inner">
                        <h3>About SpaceX</h3>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Company</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Careers</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Gallery</a><br>
                        <a class="info" href="#">Shop</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: sorry problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried about supporting old browsers, you can replace all of your css with:

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

More on flex:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

Try this code..

```
.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
position: relative;

}
.infotype {

float:left;   
color: black;
width: 30%;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```